# import sentence_transformers ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentence_transformers'

Tags: sentence-transformers

good afternoon, based on this exercise I have come across this limitation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\huggingface.py", line 58, in __init__
    import sentence_transformers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentence_transformers'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\Proyecto\aplic\privateGPT\ingest.py", line 187, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\Proyecto\aplic\privateGPT\ingest.py", line 157, in main
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=embeddings_model_name)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\huggingface.py", line 61, in __init__
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not import sentence_transformers python package. Please install it with `pip install sentence-transformers`.
```

how could i solve???

Comment: based on *what* exercise?